# Relationship between Surface and Canvas: Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

What exactly is the relationship between a Surface and Canvas.

Please explain.

Comment: This post explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576909/understanding-canvas-and-surface-concepts.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A surface is a buffer. A Canvas holds the drawing.

> Views are not attached to the Canvas
>   nor the Surface. The window is tied to
>   a Surface and the ViewRoot asks the
>   Surface for a Canvas that is then used
>   by the Views to draw onto.

For a detailled anwser, you can read this [whole discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-framework@googlegroups.com/msg01901.html), really interesting.