# What are Window and Decor in Android UI?

Tags: android

I want to know what the meanings of `Window` and `Decor` are in Android UI.

What are their tasks?

How are they different from each-other?

Answer (score 1):

### 1) Window in Android Ui?

an existing [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451755/what-is-an-android-window) could give you enough.

### 2) Decor in Android UI?

From [android-developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html)
"The DecorView is the view that actually holds the window's background drawable."

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've read that question. There is nothing mentioned about Decor. And my second question in not answered at all. Thanks anyway.