# Android terms Window and Display

Tags: android, view, window

Okay so I don't understand the difference between a display and a window in the context of android. These terms are used in different situations but like I don't know the actual distinction between them.

Comment: Every android activity is held in a window, on which, the activity UI is drawn. More on this here: [link(read the answer which _isn't_ accepted)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451755/what-is-an-android-window). `Display` - not sure if you're talking about the `Display` class. It basically gives you information on the display that is in use - eg. display's refresh-rate, size, metrics, density, oixel-format etc.

Comment: So the display is like the physical component and window is like the software component?

Comment: Sure. But, I would say they are quite separate. There's really not much to compare between the two. Do you have a specific question/confusion? Perhaps I can help you with _it_.

Comment: Thanks but not really I just wanted to know the difference between these two terms. Oh and so then what is the difference between window and surface?