# Activity animation slide from bottom

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-xml, android-transitions

What I use:

**activity_stay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

**activity_slide_to_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

**activity_slide_from_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

Start NewActivity:

```
startActivity(NewActivity.getIntent(this))
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_from_bottom, R.anim.activity_stay)
```

NewActivity finish():

```
finish()
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_stay, R.anim.activity_slide_to_bottom)
```

When NewActivity is started OldActivity disappear - I see blank white screen above which NewActivity slide to top. However what I need is my NewActivity sliding to top above the OldActivity content when started. How can I achieve this?

**UPD**: when I finish my NewActivity for some reasons all animations execute perfectly: NewActivity slide to bottom with OldActivity content appearing below NewActivity content.

Comment: try using same duration for stay `@android:integer/config_longAnimTime`

Comment: @JyotiJK Thanks for answer, i tried it but it didn't help.

Comment: this link show why you should choose the right cycle for transition animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/23752530/9287163

Comment: If you want the transition work for whole application you can create a rootacivity and inherit it in the activity you need. see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/20188089/9287163

Comment: If you want to go with your method only try to overide you finish method and add a condition of is finishing to check and pass your overidependingtranstion() method there i hardly think that might work but you can try

Comment: By these three animations what are you trying to do? What exactly you want? Just need animation on Intent  call ?

Answer (score 42):

You can achieve animations using below code :

**bottom_up.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="90%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**bottom_down.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="5"
        android:toYDelta="90%" />
</set>
```

**nothing.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

**Start Second Activity :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_up, R.anim.nothing);
```

**On finish of second activity :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.bottom_down);
}
```

**Docs.:**

> Start an activity using an animation Activity transitions in material
>   design apps provide visual connections between different states
>   through motion and transformations between common elements. You can
>   specify custom animations for enter and exit transitions and for
>   transitions of shared elements between activities.
>
> An enter transition determines how views in an activity enter the
>   scene. For example, in the explode enter transition, the views enter
>   the scene from the outside and fly in towards the center of the
>   screen. An exit transition determines how views in an activity exit
>   the scene. For example, in the explode exit transition, the views exit
>   the scene away from the center.
>
> Specify custom transitions First, enable window content transitions
>   with the android:windowActivityTransitions attribute when you define a
>   style that inherits from the material theme. You can also specify
>   enter, exit, and shared element transitions in your style definition:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">   <!-- enable window content transitions -->   
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->   
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>   
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item> </style>
```

Please check doc. [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/)

[image]

Enjoy!!

Comment: What is the difference between

android:activityOpenEnterAnimation android:activityOpenExitAnimation android:activityCloseEnterAnimation android:activityCloseExitAnimation

and

android:windowEnterTransition android:windowExitAnimation android:windowReenterTransition android:windowReturnTransition

When should you use one instead of the other?

Comment: you helped me a lot man   :) ❤

Answer (score 15):

**activity_slide_from_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

**activity_slide_to_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

**activity_stay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

**Start NewActivity:**

```
startActivity(NewActivity.getIntent(this));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_from_bottom, R.anim.activity_stay)
```

**NewActivity finish():**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_stay, R.anim.activity_slide_to_bottom);
}
```

Also, the animation can be declared in styles

```
<style name="Animation.MyCustomAnimation" parent="android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_slide_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_stay</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_stay</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_slide_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

Set this style in theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAnimTheme" parent="YourThemeParent">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.MyCustomAnimation</item>
</style>
```

Set the theme to your activity in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".NewActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
```

> **android:activityOpenEnterAnimation**
>
> When opening a new activity, this is the animation that is run on the
>   next activity (which is entering the screen)
>
> **android:activityOpenExitAnimation**
>
> When opening a new activity, this is the animation that is run on the
>   previous activity (which is exiting the screen).
>
> **android:activityCloseEnterAnimation**
>
> When closing the current activity, this is the animation that is run
>   on the next activity (which is entering the screen).
>
> **android:activityCloseExitAnimation**
>
> When closing the current activity, this is the animation that is run
>   on the current activity (which is exiting the screen).
>
> **android:windowReenterTransition**
>
> Reference to a Transition XML resource defining the desired Transition used to 
>   move Views in to the scene when returning from a previously-started
>   Activity. Corresponds to
>   `Window.setReenterTransition(android.transition.Transition).`
>
> **android:windowReturnTransition** 
>   Reference to a Transition XML resource defining the desired Transition used to >move Views out of the
>   scene when the Window is preparing to close. Corresponds to
>   `Window.setReturnTransition(android.transition.Transition).`

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr

Comment: What is the difference between

android:activityOpenEnterAnimation android:activityOpenExitAnimation android:activityCloseEnterAnimation android:activityCloseExitAnimation

and

android:windowEnterTransition android:windowExitAnimation android:windowReenterTransition android:windowReturnTransition

When should you use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to use styles, because you don't have to code in every Activity in case if you want this animation in all your activities.

**Shortest way that i use always**

*To set slide theme in all your activities*

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideAnimWindow"
    ...
    >
```

*To set slide theme in one activity*

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideAnimWindow" />
```

Put **slide_from_bottom.xml** in your **res>anim**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Put **slide_to_bottom.xml** in your **res>anim**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

Put **none.xml** in your **res>anim**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Put this style in **res>values>styles.xml**

```
<style name="SlideAnimation" parent="android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/none</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/none</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_to_bottom</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.SlideAnimWindow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/SlideAnimation</item>
</style>
```

You can change `android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"` duration according to your need.
Now you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> public void overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, 
>                   int exitAnim)
>   Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.
>
> As of Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN an alternative to using this with starting activities is to supply the desired animation information through an ActivityOptions bundle to startActivity(Intent, Bundle) or a related function. This allows you to specify a custom animation even when starting an activity from outside the context of the current top activity.

That implies Just adding `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_stay, R.anim.activity_slide_to_bottom)` after `startActivity(Intent, Bundle)` Should give the needed result.

Edit:

android:activityOpenEnterAnimation android:activityOpenExitAnimation android:activityCloseEnterAnimation android:activityCloseExitAnimation

Effects the activity

android:windowEnterTransition android:windowExitAnimation android:windowReenterTransition android:windowReturnTransition

Effects the window

For more info about activity vs window:

> An Activity has a window (in which it draws its user interface),
>
> a Window has a single Surface and a single view hierarchy attached to it,
>
> a Surface include ViewGroup which holds views.

Source: [What is an Android window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451755/what-is-an-android-window)

In conclusion, You can use them for achieving the same result but they are different.

Comment: What is the difference between

android:activityOpenEnterAnimation android:activityOpenExitAnimation android:activityCloseEnterAnimation android:activityCloseExitAnimation

and

android:windowEnterTransition android:windowExitAnimation android:windowReenterTransition android:windowReturnTransition

When should you use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 3):

I think the Animations API is more preferrable to the Transitions API for what you are trying to accomplish.  Here is a detailed explanation :
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8wqjzv/difference_between_animation_and_transitions_api/

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

## slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

## slide_out_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

## no_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

**Start NewActivity:**

```
startActivity(NewActivity.getIntent(this))
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.no_anim);
```

**NewActivity finish():**

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_down);
```