# What is meaning of "view.getWindowToken" in android?

Tags: android

I was trying to hide keyboard on click of a button.

Then I came across this code:

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

My question is what is `view.getWindowToken()` and what is the significance of it and what does it return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically all Graphical User Interface is rendered on a **Window**. One example is that of an `Activity`, from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View)

Another example would be that of an `AlertDialog`.

A screen in Android may have multiple windows. For example, you can use two activities in the multi-window Android feature. Sometimes a window can contain other windows.

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451755/what-is-an-android-window) with some good answers regarding what a **Window** is.

To answer your question, each Window has a unique identifier. This identifier is called a Window Token. So, the significance of a "WindowToken" is to uniquely identify a Window.
There is another method, namely [`getApplicationWindowToken()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getApplicationWindowToken()), which can be used to get the identifier for the top-most Window.

Comment: Then what is the difference between window and fragment?

Comment: I recommend you through the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide)

Comment: Ok, then what is the difference between window and activity

Comment: No that doesn't tell the difference. Could you please tell here?

Comment: The system uses a window to draw the status bar on, to show dialogs, to provide soft navigation keys, etc. In your application, an Activity provides this window on which UI components are shown.