# what is SurfaceView SurfaceHolder Surface Camera API android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using Camera API and bit confused with the terminology.

In simpler terms android needs a View on which the camera preview can be drawn by android SDK.
Application writer has to provide a view class to android. [There are a few restrictions and workaround so to say, which I am curios but do not know where to look].

So What is the difference between SurfaceView / SurfaceHolder and Surface.
Holder looks like a container to hold the surface but why it is needed.

Can anyone please explain these 3 terms..

Comment: Check this hope it will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view/10482872#10482872

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576909/understanding-canvas-and-surface-concepts/4577249#4577249
Yes Bharagav Rao I am agree with your point.