# Does every view have its own canvas/bitmap to draw on?

Tags: android, view

I have a relativelayout with three full screen child views of the same custom view class. I am wondering whether I should be worried about memory. Judging by this answer:
[Understanding Canvas and Surface concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576909/understanding-canvas-and-surface-concepts)

All views get passed the same canvas with underlying bitmap to draw on so that the memory is not tripled. Can anyone confirm? 
It would make sense, otherwise a full screen textview would be very inefficient.

Bonus: is the purpose of canvas to define a drawable area of a bitmap and translating the view coordinates to bitmap coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas:

> When you're writing an application in which you would like to perform specialized drawing and/or control the animation of graphics, you should do so by drawing through a Canvas. A Canvas works for you as a pretense, or interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn — it holds all of your "draw" calls. Via the Canvas, your drawing is actually performed upon an underlying Bitmap, which is placed into the window.

In the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, you are given a `canvas` object. This `canvas` has an underlying `bitmap`. All views are not given the same canvas. Canvas is just a layer above the common `bitmap` (which is pixels on the screen). `canvas` offers you to manipulate the `bitmap` as much as you want. So every view has a canvas, but not it's own bitmap.

So no, as far as memory is concerned, three view doesn't mean memory is tripled, because there is just `one` bitmap. You could however create your own `bitmap`, if you do so, then you will be jogging up the memory. If you create 3 bitmaps with size of the screen, your memory will be tripled.